# ansible lineinfile replace a line begin containing a pattern with default ports in multiple files based on input array

Tags: ansible

```yaml
--- 
- 
  gather_facts: true
  hosts: abc,pqr,xyz
  name: "playbook"
  serial: 1
  tasks: 
    - 
      block: 
        - 
          shell: "ls /etc/maria/"       # could be n number of ports like 123, 456, 789
          register: ports
          
        - 
          lineinfile: 
            line: PORT={{ new_ports }}
            path: "/etc/instance_{{ item }}/mariadb.conf"
            regexp: '^PORT='
            with_items: "{{ ports.stdout_lines }}"
            new_ports:                          # length of this would be based on number of ports, should create an array based on array size of `ports` 
        - 8880
        - 8881
        - 8882
```

Say for example I've some 3 ports from `ls /etc/maria/`  
 `123`
`456`
`789`
 and 3 corresponding files 
`/etc/instance_123/mariadb.conf`, 
`/etc/instance_456/mariadb.conf`, 
`/etc/instance_789/mariadb.conf`.

could be n number of ports & files. 
I would like to replace line starting with ^PORT= in  `/etc/instance_123/mariadb.conf` to PORT=8880 and so on until the length of array ports.

##### Results getting with suggested code:

##### Before

```sh
/etc/instance_1234/mariadb.conf | grep port
port=1234
```

##### playbook

```sh
- hosts: abc
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - shell: ls /etc/maria/
      register: ports

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ports.stdout_lines|length }}"

    - lineinfile:
        path: "/etc/instance_{{ item }}/mariadb.conf"
        regexp: "^port=.*$"
        line: "port={{ new_ports[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
      loop: "{{ ports.stdout_lines }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
        new_ports: "{{ range(8880, 8880 + ports.stdout_lines|length) }}"
```

##### After

```sh
/etc/instance_1234/mariadb.conf | grep port
port=x
```

Comment: The *regexp/line* can't work. It's case-sensitive.

Comment: that's my bad, even with lower case port its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, given the files

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 ls /tmp/mongo
123
456
```

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_12 ls /tmp/mongo
123
456
789
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - command: ls /tmp/mongo
      register: ports
    - lineinfile:
        path: "/tmp/etc/instance_{{ item }}/mongodb.conf"
        regexp: "^PORT=.*$"
        line: "PORT={{ new_ports[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ ports.stdout_lines }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
        new_ports: "{{ range(8880, 8880 + ports.stdout_lines|length) }}"
```

creates, or updates the configuration files

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 ls /tmp/etc/
instance_123
instance_456

shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/etc/instance_123/mongodb.conf
PORT=8880

shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/etc/instance_456/mongodb.conf
PORT=8881
```

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_12 ls /tmp/etc/
instance_123
instance_456
instance_789

shell> ssh admin@test_12 cat /tmp/etc/instance_123/mongodb.conf
PORT=8880

shell> ssh admin@test_12 cat /tmp/etc/instance_456/mongodb.conf
PORT=8881

shell> ssh admin@test_12 cat /tmp/etc/instance_789/mongodb.conf
PORT=8882
```

Comment: can this achieved with with_items, may be my ansible not supporting loop and loop_control ?

Comment: for some reason line `^port=` is replaced by `port=x`